# Python - one result from a list

Tags: python

I dont know if i did choose a good title, but here it goes:

I have this list which i need it to only produce one result not all of them!

```
for i in range(len(F)):
    print i+1,D[i]

1 -0.0002
2 0.0
3 0.0
4 0.0
5 -3.2e-05
6 -0.000376
```

I need only the last result. I use a for loop to get all of them. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `print len(F), D[len(F)-1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just index the last element which will be `your_list[-1]` so:

```
print(D[-1])
```

If `F` is not the length as `D` just use `F -1` to index the list:

```
print(D[F-1])
```

Comment: LOL! I got the answer so fast stackoverflow wouldn't let me accept it :D
You can accept an answer in 7 minutes